How can i fix the Cannot read property '$id' of undefined error
export async function updateWriter(writerId, form) {
  try {
    const updates = {};

    
    if (form.writerName) {
      updates.writer_name = form.writerName;
    }
    if (form.writerSurname) {
      updates.writer_surname = form.writerSurname;
    }
    if (form.writerLifeSummary) {
      updates.life_summary = form.writerLifeSummary;
    }
    if (form.writerProfilePicture) {
      const [writerProfilePictureUrl] = await Promise.all([
        uploadFile(form.writerProfilePicture, "image")
      ]);
      updates.writer_profile_picture = writerProfilePictureUrl;
    }
    console.log(writerId);
    const updatedWriter = await databases.updateDocument(
      appWriteConfig.databaseId,
      appWriteConfig.writersCollectionId,
      writerId,
      updates
    );

    return updatedWriter;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
} 

this is my update function to updating writers from appwrite database.
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, FlatList, TouchableOpacity, Image, Modal ,Alert} from 'react-native';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import useAppwrite from '../../lib/useAppwrite';
import { getAllWriters,updateWriter} from '../../lib/appwrite'; 
import { icons } from '../../constants';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import { useEffect } from 'react';


const UpdateWriter = () => {
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
  const [selectedWriter, setSelectedWriter] = useState(null);
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const { data, refetch } = useAppwrite(getAllWriters);
  
  const [uploading, setUploading] = useState(false);
  const [form,setForm] = useState({
    writerId:'',
    writerName:'',
    writerSurname:'',
    writerLifeSummary:'',
    writerProfilePicture:null
  })
  

  const handleUpdateItem = (item) => {
    setSelectedWriter(item);
    setForm({
      writerId: item.$id,
      writerName: item.writer_name,
      writerSurname: item.writer_surname,
      writerLifeSummary: item.life_summary,
      writerProfilePicture: item.writer_profile_picture,
    });
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedWriter) {
      console.log(selectedWriter.$id); // Doğru writerId'yi yazdırır 
      setForm(prevForm => ({
        ...prevForm,
        writerId: selectedWriter.$id, 
      }));
      setModalVisible(true);
    } 
  }, [selectedWriter]);
  

  const handleModalClose = () => {
    setSelectedWriter(null);
    setModalVisible(false);
  };
  
  const openPicker = async (selectType) =>{
    let result = await ImagePicker.
    launchImageLibraryAsync({
     mediaTypes: selectType === 'image' ? ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images:ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Videos,
     aspect : [4,3],
     quality:1
    });

    if(!result.canceled){
     if(selectType==='image'){
       setForm({...form,writerProfilePicture:result.assets[0]})
     }
  
    }
 }
  const handleFormSubmit = async () => {

    
    if(!form.writerName || !form.writerSurname || !form.writerLifeSummary || !form.writerProfilePicture){
      return Alert.alert("Hata","Lütfen tüm alanları eksiksiz doldurduğunuzdan emin olunuz");
    }
    setUploading(true);
    try {
      

      await updateWriter(form.writerId,form); 
      Alert.alert("Başarılı","Yazar başarıyla güncellendi");
      setModalVisible(false);
      refetch();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Yazar güncellenirken bir hata oluştu:', error);
      
    }
    finally{
      setForm({
        writerId:'',
        writerName:'',
        writerSurname:'',
        writerLifeSummary:'',
        writerProfilePicture:null
      })
      setUploading(false);
      setModalVisible(false);
      refetch();
    }
    
  };

  

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <View className="flex-row justify-between items-center px-2 border-2 mb-2 w-[95%] self-center bg-secondary border-secondary-100 rounded-xl overflow-auto">
      <Image source={{ uri: item.writer_profile_picture }} className="w-[40px] h-[40px] rounded-full" resizeMode='cover' />
      <Text className="text-white font-psemibold text-xl max-w-[55%] text-center">{item.writer_name} {item.writer_surname}</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>handleUpdateItem(item)}>
        <Text className="font-psemibold text-xl text-orange-500">Güncelle</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );

  const filteredData = data.filter(item =>
    item.writer_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
  );

  return (
    <SafeAreaView className="bg-primary h-full">
      <Text className="text-white text-2xl text-center mt-5 font-psemibold">Yazar Güncelle</Text>
      <View className="bg-secondary-100 mt-5 mb-5 w-[95%] self-center rounded-xl flex-row justify-between items-center">
        <TextInput
          className="m-5 w-[80%] text-white"
          placeholder="Güncellemek istediğiniz yazarı aratın.."
          placeholderTextColor={"white"}
          value={searchText}
          onChangeText={text => setSearchText(text)}
        />
        <Image
          source={icons.search}
          className="w-[30px] h-[30px] mr-2"
          resizeMode='contain'
        />
      </View>
      <Text className="text-white text-lg text-center mb-2">Toplam {data.length} yazar listeleniyor</Text>
      <FlatList
        data={filteredData}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.$id.toString()}
        className="mb-10"
      />

      <Modal
        visible={modalVisible}
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        onRequestClose={handleModalClose}>
        <View className="flex-1 justify-center items-center" style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)' }}>
          <View className="bg-secondary-100 p-5 rounded-lg w-[90%]">
            <Text className="text-xl text-white font-psemibold mb-5">Yazar Bilgilerini Güncelle</Text>
            <Text>{form.writerId}</Text>
            <Text className="text-white mb-2 text-lg font-psemibold">Yazarın Adı</Text>
            <TextInput
              className=" border-white border-2 p-3 mb-5 text-white font-pregular"
              placeholder="Lütfen yazarın adını giriniz..."
              placeholderTextColor={"white"}
              value={form.writerName}
              onChangeText={(e)=>setForm({...form,writerName:e})}
            />
            <Text className="text-white mb-2 text-lg font-psemibold">Yazarın Soyadı</Text>
            <TextInput
              className=" border-white border-2 p-3 mb-5 text-white font-pregular"
              placeholder="Yazarın Soyadı"
              placeholderTextColor={"white"}
              value={form.writerSurname}
              onChangeText={(e)=>setForm({...form,writerSurname:e})}
            />
            <Text className="text-white mb-2 text-lg font-psemibold">Yazarın Hayatı</Text>
             <TextInput
              className=" border-white border-2 p-3 mb-5 text-white font-pregular max-h-[20%]"
              placeholder="Yazarın Soyadı"
              placeholderTextColor={"white"}
              value={form.writerLifeSummary}
              onChangeText={(e)=>setForm({...form,writerLifeSummary:e})}
              multiline
            
            />
           <Text className="text-white mb-2 text-lg font-psemibold">Yazar Fotoğrafı</Text>
           <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>openPicker('image')}>
            {form.writerProfilePicture ? (
              <Image
              source={{uri:form.writerProfilePicture.uri}}
              resizeMode='cover'
              className="w-[98%]  h-20 rounded-lg self-center"
              />
            ):(
              <View className="w-[95%] h-11 px-4 bg-secondary rounded-2xl justify-center items-center
               flex-row space-x-2 self-center">
                
                  <Image
                  source={icons.upload}
                  resizeMode='contain'
                  className="w-5 h-5"/>
                  <Text className="text-sm text-white font-pmedium">Resim Seç</Text>
                
              </View>
            )} 
          </TouchableOpacity>

          



            <View className="flex-row justify-between">
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleModalClose} className="bg-red-700 p-3 rounded-lg mt-5 w-[30%] items-center">
                <Text className="text-white font-semibold text-base">Kapat</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleFormSubmit()} className=" bg-orange-600 p-3 rounded-lg mt-5 w-[30%] items-center">
                <Text className="text-white font-semibold text-base">Güncelle</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

export default UpdateWriter;


and this is my react native page. Whenever i click the 'guncelle' button on writer and changing the datas and click to other 'guncelle' button in modal i get [Error: Error: TypeError: Cannot read property '$id' of undefined] error. Is there anyone who help me
I tried to update data from appwrite database and get the [Error: Error: TypeError: Cannot read property '$id' of undefined] error
